# jQuery capitalizing field names from XML return?

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I'm outputting this XML from a PHP page and parsing the result in jQuery:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <response> <row> <webpage_tag_id>2096</webpage_tag_id> <stackPageID>Test</stackPageID> </row> <row> <webpage_tag_id>2175</webpage_tag_id> <stackPageID>Test</stackPageID> </row> </response>
```

When I console.log the result in jQuery, I get:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
STACKPAGEID: "Test"
WEBPAGE_TAG_ID: "2096"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
STACKPAGEID: "Test"
WEBPAGE_TAG_ID: "2175"
```

Great but why are the fields capitalized? The problem is the following code outputs "undefined":

```
$.each(updateArr, function(index,item) {            
    console.log(item.webpage_tag_id);
});
```

...but this returns the correct result:

```
   $.each(updateArr, function(index,item) {         
        console.log(item.WEBPAGE_TAG_ID);
    });
```

Has anyone heard of an issue like this?

This is the fuunction I use to parse:

```
$(xml).find("row").each(function () {   

        var idx=0;
        var name='';
        var $currentNode = $(this);
        var rowObj = new Object();  
        var nodeName = $currentNode.children()[idx].nodeName;

        while( nodeName ) 
        {
            rowObj[nodeName] = $currentNode.find(nodeName).text();

            if ($currentNode.children()[idx]) {
                 nodeName = $currentNode.children()[idx].nodeName
            } else {
                nodeName=false;
            }

            idx++;
        }

        arr.push(rowObj);       
    });
```

Comment: how are you parsing it

Comment: I updated the question to show how I parse

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/

Answer (score 3):

`$(string)` parses the string as **HTML** (using the DOM APIs), which the browser normalizes to uppercase.

You want `$.parseXML(xml)`, which returns a real XML DOM.
You probably also want to create a jQuery object around that.  (`$(XML DOM element)` is fine and will not parse as HTML)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: $.parseXML solved the problem. Goddamn... I spent hours on this. Thanks for solving my problem in 5 minutes SLaks!